# Adding In-App Purchases (Cocoa) - Simple Tutorials?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, in-app-purchase

For a total noob, are there any recommended tutorials to implement in-app purchases (non-consumable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial is for iOS, but it should translate with minor modification to OSX (you didn't flag your question as iOS or OSX):

[Introduction to In-App Purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases).

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out this tutorial:

[In App Purchases: A full walkthrough](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

And just in case you run into a common "Invalid product ID" error (I spent plenty of time scratching my head on this one), here is a good checklist to check if you missed anything:

[Invalid product IDs](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small simple helper for this task for Obj-C

https://github.com/wizalx/WIZPurchaseHelper

Firstly, you must add method to AppDelegate:

```
[[WIZPurchaseHelper sharedInstance] validateProductIdentifiers:@[@"yourId0",@"yourId1"];
```

Secondly, you must add functionality to purchase screen. For example:

```
[[WIZPurchaseHelper sharedInstance] payWithIdentefier:@"yourIdent"];
```

Finally, don't forget to add delegate methods that will tell you whether the purchase is successful or not!

I use this helper all the time when I work with shopping, but I turn into my own manager